# Is there a prefix/Polish notation for the equality operator in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, pointfree

I'm learning Elixir, and one of the exercises I've decided to give myself is to try and write the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for credit card validation in idiomatic Elixir.

I realize that `==` in Elixir is a Kernel function, which are apparently inlined by the compiler. Is there some kind of utility function that will let me do something like this?

```
...
|> == 0
```

instead of having to define a function to pipe into, as I've done here.

**Elixir**

```
defmodule Luhn do
  def equalzero?(x) x == 0 end
  def validate(num) do
    digits = Integer.digits(num)
    len = length digits

    digits
    |> Stream.with_index
    |> Enum.reverse
    |> Enum.reduce(0, fn {digit, index}, acc ->
      if rem(len - index, 2) == 0 do
        acc + digit * 2 |> Integer.digits |> Enum.sum
      else
        acc + digit
      end
    end)
    |> rem(10)
    |> Luhn.equalzero?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe into such operators (which are defined in `Kernel`) by referring to their full path, `Kernel.==`:

```
iex(1)> 0 |> Kernel.==(0)
true
iex(2)> 1 |> Kernel.==(0)
false
```